# Store two fields with same name but different id on same, row in mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have a project where customer can select price base on checkbox and input both have same name,
I want if i choose checkbox and not input, I can store only checkbox in db, if i choose, input and can only store the value of input.
here is my code

```
<ul class="donate-now">[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyU7O.png)
                  <li>
                    <input type="radio" class="form-control btn-default target" id="a100" name="amount" value="100"/>
                    <label for="a25">100€/mois</label>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <input type="radio" class="form-control btn-default target" id="a200" name="amount" value="200" />
                    <label for="a50">200€/mois</label>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <input type="radio" class="form-control btn-default target" id="a300" name="amount" value="300" checked/>
                    <label for="a75">300€/mois</label>
                  </li>
                 
                </ul>
                </div>
              
            
                
                <div class="container form-control-lg" id="montant-libre">
                  <span class="input-symbol-euro"><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-md" style="color: #d34607;" id="montantlibre" onclick="clearRadio()"  placeholder="Montant libre" name="amount" min="1"/></span>
                  
                </div>
```

should i change something on my mysql, because i always get error

should i change something on my mysql, because i always get error

Comment: These are radio buttons, not checkboxes. If the user chooses a radio button, make the text input disabled and it won't be sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form id="donate">
   <ul class="donate-now">
      <li>
         <input type="radio" class="form-control btn-default target" id="a100" name="amount" value="100"/>
         <label for="a25">100€/mois</label>
      </li>
      <li>
         <input type="radio" class="form-control btn-default target" id="a200" name="amount" value="200" />
         <label for="a50">200€/mois</label>
      </li>
      <li>
         <input type="radio" class="form-control btn-default target" id="a300" name="amount" value="300" checked/>
         <label for="a75">300€/mois</label>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <div class="container form-control-lg" id="montant-libre">
      <span class="input-symbol-euro">
      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-md" style="color: #d34607;" id="montantlibre" onclick="clearRadio()"  placeholder="Montant libre" name="amount" min="1"/>
      </span>
   </div>
</form>
<script>
   // Get the form element
   var form = document.getElementById("donate");
   if (form) {
   // Add a submit event listener to the form
   form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
     // Get the selected radio button
     var selectedRadio = document.querySelector('input[name="amount"]:checked');
   
     // Get the input field
     var inputField = document.getElementById("montantlibre");
     var amount = selectedRadio.value;
     // Check if the input field has a value
     if (!Number(inputField.value) !== true) {
       // new value
        amount = inputField.value;
     }
   
     console.log(amount);
     // Prevent the default form submission
     event.preventDefault();
   });
   }
</script>
```

Details:

1-Get the form element using `document.getElementById("donate")`.

2-Add a submit event listener to the form using `form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) { ... });`.

3-Inside the event listener function, get the selected radio button using `document.querySelector('input[name="amount"]:checked')`.

4-Get the input field using `document.getElementById("montantlibre")`.

5-Check if the input field has a value using `if (!Number(inputField.value) !== true) { ... }`.

6-If the input field has a value, store that value in the amount variable. Otherwise, store the value of the selected radio button in the amount variable.

7-Prevent the default form submission using `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but there is a missing part, sorry to disturb. how i return the value of checkbox if there is no value on inputField